# Write Progress Bar till Get-Job Return "Running" PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

i have a set of job's which are running.

```
PS C:\vinith> Get-Job

Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
2      scvmm2012-vin   BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            Param...
4      scom2012sp1-vin BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            Param...
6      scorch2012-vin  BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            Param...
8      scsm2012sp1-vin BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            Param...
10     spfoundation    BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            Param...
```

I want a progress bar display till the jobs are running and should say completed when the job state becomes "completed" in powershell

Comment: [Here's a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317438/monitoring-jobs-in-a-powershell-session-from-another-powershell-session)

Answer (score 5):

Use `Write-Progress` for the progress bar. Use `Get-Job` to receive number of current jobs. Like so,

```
# Some dummy jobs for illustration purposes
start-job -ScriptBlock { start-sleep -Seconds 5 }
start-job -ScriptBlock { start-sleep -Seconds 10 }
start-job -ScriptBlock { start-sleep -Seconds 15 }
start-job -ScriptBlock { start-sleep -Seconds 20 }
start-job -ScriptBlock { start-sleep -Seconds 25 }

# Get all the running jobs
$jobs = get-job | ? { $_.state -eq "running" }
$total = $jobs.count
$runningjobs = $jobs.count

# Loop while there are running jobs
while($runningjobs -gt 0) {
    # Update progress based on how many jobs are done yet.
    write-progress -activity "Events" -status "Progress:" `
   -percentcomplete (($total-$runningjobs)/$total*100)

    # After updating the progress bar, get current job count
    $runningjobs = (get-job | ? { $_.state -eq "running" }).Count
}
```

Comment: Hello Von, i tried it but i do not see any status for -percentcomplete?, its just showing up as blank, here's the job which i started, Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-Process| ConvertTo-Json}, and ran your script above to show progress but i did not see any status for percent complete --> it did not advance with small "o" dots, it was just blank

Comment: Worked for me. Of course you'll only see progress once jobs are not in `Running` state anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in your while block to have a value in the progress bar as well

```
while($runningjobs -gt 0) {
# Update progress based on how many jobs are done yet.
$percent=[math]::Round((($total-$runningjobs)/$total * 100),2)
write-progress -activity "Starting Provisioning Modules Instances" -status "Progress: $percent%" -percentcomplete (($total-$runningjobs)/$total*100)

# After updating the progress bar, get current job count
$runningjobs = (get-job | ? { $_.state -eq "running" }).Count
```