# PowerShell: Do/Until loop until multiple jobs are completed

Tags: powershell, loops, jobs

Morning folks,

I'm working on a `Do/Until` loop that tracks an `invoke-command` job against multiple servers. What I don't know how to capture in the `Until` block is to continue doing the loop until all servers report a `Completed` status.

below is my test code

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01,Server02,Server03 -ScriptBlock{sleep -s 120} -AsJob -JobName "Test Job"

Do{
Write-Host "Job is still running"
sleep -s 10
}Until((Get-Job "Test Job").state -eq "Completed"
```

I'm thinking I need to put the following in the Until block but I'm not sure

```
Until(ForEach($job in (Get-Job "Test Job")){
$Job.State -eq "Completed"
})
```

Comment: wait-job or receive-job -wait

Comment: Are you doing this for a specific reason? Like tracking progress?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon yes I'm doing it to track progress.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71918277/add-write-progress-to-get-job-wait-job/71918903#71918903

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that post seems to be a better answer to what I was looking for than I thought. I’ve given it some slight testing today and will continue into tomorrow

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I’m wondering if you could help me out a bit here. I’m taking your function from your answer you posted above. I’m wanting to change the progress bar into seconds remaining from ``timeout`` value, but I can’t for the life of me figure that part out and could use a nudge in the right direction

Comment: I think it's worth asking a new question for this, you can make a reference of my function. I'm pretty busy right now but likely you can get a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the means to test this at the moment, but if you're after a progress output, I don't see why this wouldn't work.

```
$jobs = Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01,Server02,Server03 -ScriptBlock{sleep -s 120} -AsJob
do {
    foreach ($job in ($jobs.ChildJobs | ? 'State' -EQ 'Running')
    {
        Write-Host -Object (
            "Job {0} is still running on computer {1}." -f $job.Name, $job.Location
        )
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
} until ($jobs.ChildJobs.State -notcontains 'Running')
```

As mentioned above, I don't have the means to test this, nor do I recall if the **State** property you'd get from the parent job takes into account for the child jobs running. Technically speaking, what you tried would have worked as well given it had the closing parenthesis.

```
Do{
Write-Host "Job is still running"
sleep -s 10
}Until((Get-Job "Test Job").state -eq "Completed")
```

I didn't account for every issue you may come across but one thing you may be wary of is that the **State** property may not always be in a "Completed", or "Running" state. This could lead to an indefinite loop testing for a "Completed" status.