# Edit custom function progress bar to use seconds remaining from a fixed amount of seconds

Tags: powershell, function, math, progress-bar

Afternoon all,

I’m using this function provided by Santiago Squarzon [Add Write-Progress to Get-Job/Wait-Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71918277/add-write-progress-to-get-job-wait-job/71918903#71918903)

I’m looking to change the progress bar to SecondsRemaining based off the `$Timeout` value

Below is the Write-Progress snippet from the full function.

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace System.Diagnostics
using namespace System.Threading
using namespace System.Management.Automation

function Wait-JobWithProgress {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Job[]] $InputObject,

        [parameter()]
        [double] $TimeOut
    )

    begin {
        $timer = [Stopwatch]::StartNew()
        $jobs  = [List[Job]]::new()
    }

    process {
        foreach($job in $InputObject) {
            $jobs.Add($job)
        }
    }

    end {
        $total      = $jobs.Count
        $completed  = 0
        $expression = { $true }

        if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('TimeOut')) {
            $expression = { $timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -le $TimeOut }
        }

        while((& $expression) -and $jobs) {
            $status = “running job. Timeout in $($timeout / 60) minutes”

            $progress = @{
                Activity        = 'Waiting for Jobs'
                SecondsRemaining = #this is where I’m stuck
                Status          = $status
            }
            Write-Progress @progress
```

I’m stuck on how to get the math to properly work for counting down based off the `$timeout` value.

An example command is

```
Start-Job {sleep -s 60} | Wait-JobWithProgress -Timeout 120
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `SecondsRemaining = $TimeOut - $timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds` but that will just work as long as `-TimeOut` is being used, I coded it in such a way that this parameter is optional

Comment: Thanks! I’ll give it a try tonight. I was looking to edit it this way for how I’m implementing it as I want the job to stop if it’s been running for 30 minutes but I wanted to have it reflect that information

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I've made some tweaks and got it to how I feel like I want it to look/work. however I am running into an issue I can't figure out. The ``percentcomplete`` bar will reset back to the beginning after every minute while running. any ideas?

Comment: the calculation for `PercentComplete` should not be changed the formula should remain the same ( `completedJobs / totalJobs * 100`)

Answer (score 0):

PercentComplete is the actual progress bar itself and a needed parameter for that to work. If you're looking to add the remaining time, it would go in your Status.

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace System.Diagnostics
using namespace System.Threading
using namespace System.Management.Automation

function Wait-JobWithProgress {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Job[]] $InputObject,

        [parameter()]
        [double] $TimeOut
    )

    begin {
        $timer = [Stopwatch]::StartNew()
        $jobs  = [List[Job]]::new()
    }

    process {
        foreach($job in $InputObject) {
            $jobs.Add($job)
        }
    }

    end {
        $is_done    = $false
        $total      = $jobs.Count
        $completed  = 0
        $expression = { $true }

        if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('TimeOut')) {
            $expression = { $timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -le $TimeOut }
        }

        while(& $expression -and $jobs) {
            $status = 'Remaining Jobs {0} of {1}. Seconds remaining: {2}.' -f @(
                ($jobs.State -eq 'Running').Count
                $total
                $timeout - $timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
            )

            $progress = @{
                Activity        = 'Waiting for Jobs'
                PercentComplete = $completed / $total * 100
                Status          = $status
                Completed       = $is_done
            }

            if ($completed -ne $total) { Write-Progress @progress }
            elseif ($completed -eq $total -and -not $is_done)
            {
                $is_done = $true
                Remove-Variable -Name 'jobs'
            }
            elseif ($is_done) { Break }

            foreach ($completed_job in $jobs.Where{$_.State -ne 'Running'})
            {
                $completed_job
                $index = [array]::IndexOf($jobs,$completed_job,0)
                $jobs.RemoveAt($index)
                $completed++
            }
        }

        # Stop the jobs not yet Completed and remove them
        if ($jobs)
        {
            $jobs | Stop-Job -PassThru | ForEach-Object {
                Remove-Job -Job $_
                "Job [#{0} - {1}] did not complete on time and was removed." -f $_.Id, $_.Name
            } | Write-Warning
            $is_completed = $true
            Write-Progress @progress 
        }
    }
}
```

I was having some trouble with the original code and modified it for my use, but the solution is in the `$status` variable.