# How to insert break or key sequence info powershell job

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, netmon

I am trying to run netmon on a series of machines, I am able to start netmon, which appears to be fine. However when I issue a `Stop-Job *` it appears that netmon is not closing correctly, which causes the packet capture to be useless. Netmon is expecting a "ctrl + C" , is there a way to issue this when I am stopping the jobs? Netmon can use other key sequences using the /stopwhen /keypress option is used

```
$server = get-content C:\Server.txt 
$capturedevice = "CAPTUREMACHINE"

foreach ($server in $server)
{ $scriptBlockContent = { param ($servername)
Nmcap /capture /network * /file C:\temp\"$servername".chn:400MB } 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Scriptblock $scriptBlockContent -ArgumentList $server -AsJob }

foreach ($capturedevice in $capturedevice){ $scriptBlockContent = 
{ param ($capturedevicename) Nmcap /capture /network * /file D:\temp\"$capturedevicename".chn:400MB } 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $capturedevice -Scriptblock $scriptBlockContent -ArgumentList $capturedevice -AsJob }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ready solution for you, but here is some food for thought.

You have 2 issues to take care of:

1. You need to gracefuly close `Nmcap` process, so it could save the capture file.

   1. You can try to go with `Start-Process`:

      ```
      $nmcap = Start-Process -FilePath "Nmcap" -ArgumentList  "/capture /network * /file C:\temp\"$servername".chn:400MB"

      $nmcap.Close() #or $nmcap.CloseMainWindow()
      $nmcap.WaitForExit()
      ```
   2. Or if code above wouldn't work using `$nmcap.Close()` or `$nmcap.CloseMainWindow()`, then you cloud try to send <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to the `Nmcap`:

      ```
      $Wasp = Add-Type -MemberDefinition @'
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
      '@ -Passthru
      $null = Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms

      if($Wasp::SetForegroundWindow($nmcap.MainWindowHandle)) {
          [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^C")
          $nmcap.WaitForExit()
      }
      ```
   3. If everything fails, you could try to adopt C# solution: [Stopping command-line applications programatically with Ctrl-C event from .Net – a working demo](http://stanislavs.org/stopping-command-line-applications-programatically-with-ctrl-c-events-from-net)
2. To gracefuly close `Nmcap` process you have to detect inside the job when PowerShell tries to stop this job.

   1. File based approach: [How To Gracefully Stop An Asynchronous Job In PowerShell](https://codepumpkin.wordpress.com/2014/11/17/gracefully-stop-an-asynchronous-job-in-powershell/)
   2. Event-Based approach: [Monitoring jobs in a PowerShell session from another PowerShell session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317438/monitoring-jobs-in-a-powershell-session-from-another-powershell-session). But you'd have to reverse the code and send signal to the job, I've not tried it, so I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Thanks, ill give these a shot.