# handle powershell event in custom cmdlet code

Tags: powershell, events

I'm trying to stop remote powershell job gracefully by using event. There are some good examples to do this with powershell cmdlets (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317438/monitoring-jobs-in-a-powershell-session-from-another-powershell-session)).

But I don't know how to do the same thing from my custom cmdlet in C# code.

My solution is like following:

1. Invoke CustomCmdlet as job in remote machine:

   Invoke-Command -Session $sess -AsJob -ScriptBlock { CustomCmdlet }
2. Inside my CustomCmdlet C# code

   ```
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        // Question: How to write the C# code for following cmdlet? How to set my CancelJob function in the Action parameter?
        // Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier MyEventSource -Action { CancelJob() }

        // Start a new task thread to run the real task
    }

    private void CancelJob()
    {
       // Get the event to cancel the job. 
       // Notify the task thread to clean up server resource and exit
    }
   ```
3. When need to cancel the job, send an event to remote machine:

Invoke-Command -Session $sess -AsJob -ScriptBlock {New-Event -SourceIdentifier MyEventSource -MessageData "CancelTheJob" }

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `this.Events.SubscribeEvent`

Comment: Thanks a lot @PetSerAl ! I will try that out.